# How to maximum L1 norm problem?

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

I have met a problem these days.
\begin{equation}
\underset{\omega}{\max}  \quad \Vert \text{diag}(\mathbf{h}^H)\mathbf{G}^H\mathbf{\omega}\Vert_1 \\
s.t.\quad\mathbf{\omega}^H\mathbf{G}\mathbf{G}^H\mathbf{\omega}=t\\
\quad\mathbf{\omega}^H\mathbf{\omega}\leq 1
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{h}$ and $\mathbf{G}$ are fixed; Superscript H and $\Vert*\Vert_1$ denote complex conjugate transpose and complex 1 norm, respectively.

For any given $t$, how to solve this problem. In other words, how to build a relationship between $t$ and objective function.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any assumption on $\mathbf{h}$ or $\mathbf{G}$? What is the range of values of $t$? Indeed, for some given $\mathbf{G}$ and $t$ it is not clear that there exists $\omega$ satisfying both constraints.

Comment: Denote the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{G}\mathbf{G^H}$ is $ \lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \ldots\geq \lambda_N$. According to the two constraints, I think the range of values of $t$ is no more than $\lambda_1$. So, I hope to build the relationship between $t (0\leq t\leq \lambda_1)$ and the objective function. This problem has troubled me for a long time. Thanks for you help.

Comment: You can apply a numerical non-convex non;linear optimizer.